# Apache2 limit download speed

Tags: ubuntu, download, apache2, limit, ubuntu-10.10

Can you help me? I am trying to find a way to limit download speed from my server, i found such module as mod_bandwidth, but there is no howto on apache2.2 only for 1.3.x

How can I limit download speed.
I have ubuntu 10.10 and apache2.2 on my server.

Answer (score 2):

you should give [libapache2-mod-bw](http://apache.ivn.cl/#bandwidth) a try, it should be available in ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1):

Some links:

> http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling
>
> http://blog.mansonthomas.com/2009/02/limit-upload-bandwith-of-your-apache.html
>
> http://www.vttoth.com/bandwidth.htm